# Задача: прокликать весь список, теряется один элемент

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Стоит задача: прокликать меню и подгруппы. С подгруппами проблем нет, есть проблема с основным меню, второй пункт меню мой тест почему-то пропускает постоянно. Количество пунктов меню находится верно, `xpath` верный.

Код:

```
   List<WebElement> firstmenutList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='side-bar-second__items']"));
   int numberOfListElements = firstmenutList.size();
   System.out.println(numberOfListElements);

   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfListElements-1; i++){
        firstmenutList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='side-bar-second__items']"));
        int FnumberOfListElements = firstmenutList.size();
        System.out.println(FnumberOfListElements);

        System.out.println(firstmenutList.get(i).getText());
        System.out.println(i);
        firstmenutList.get(i).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        List<WebElement> secondmenutList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='side-bar-third'][contains(@style, 'display: block')]/ul/li"));
        int secondnumberOfListElements = secondmenutList.size();
        System.out.println(secondnumberOfListElements);
        for (int j = 0; j < secondnumberOfListElements ; j++){
            secondmenutList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='side-bar-third'][contains(@style, 'display: block')]/ul/li"));
            System.out.println(j);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(secondmenutList.get(j).getText());
            secondmenutList.get(j).click();
       }
   }
```

`numberOfListElements-1` - потому как, если брать `numberOfListElements`, то тест, естественно, заваливается.

Comment: *потому как, если брать `numberOfListElements`, то тест, естественно, заваливается* - почему естественно? Почему с `secondnumberOfListElements` он не заваливается?

Comment: Понятия не имею, я для контроля вывожу все названия пунктов меню. Вот пункты верхнего уровня выходят так: Пункт1, Пункт3, Пункт4, Пункт5 и тд. А пункты второго уровня все выводятся без пропусков. Знать бы... Естественно - потому что пунктов меню по факту 18, тест кликает 17, второй пропускает, хотя в .size(); он его посчитал.

Comment: Решилось. Изменением xpath. Хотя количество считал он верное, просто не кликал.